# Renaming all subdirectories using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a deeply nested folder structure on a Windows 7 machine. Windows refuses to delete the directories as their names are too long. I want to rename all subfolders to something like `2` in the hope that it will be short enough to be deleted. This is my script:

```
@count = 0

Dir.glob("**/*") do |file|  #find src files in current folder and all subfolders
  if File.directory?(file)
    File.rename(file, File.dirname(file) + File::SEPARATOR + "2")
    @count += 1
  end
end

puts @count
```

When the script runs, instead of renaming all sub-directories, it changes one more sub-directory, gradually going one level deeper each time. I.e., the output from running the script at the moment is:

```
C:\>renamer.rb
30
C:\>renamer.rb
31
C:\>renamer.rb
32
```

I'm confused as to why this is happening and would appreciate any input.

Am I taking the correct approach? I assume Ruby's recursive directory deletion methods would fail. However, when I try and execute

```
require "FileUtils"
FileUtils.remove_dir ("2", force = true)
```

I get the error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
FileUtils.remove_dir ("2", force = true)
                          ^
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
FileUtils.remove_dir ("2", force = true)
                                    ^
```

Comment: Here `FileUtils.remove_dir ("2", force = true)` why *2* ? why not the full file path ?

Comment: I didn't use the full path as the directory "2" is in the current working directory

Comment: Is your 2 parts of code,in the same `.rb` file? Are they executing separately ?

Comment: [Don't put a space before the parenthesis.](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#source-code-layout). Thus says the style-guide.

Comment: @Babai they're executing separately. I just thought I'd try the remove_dir. Apologies for the confusion - I'll remain the remove_dir script in the question

Comment: @screenmutt Nice link. I didn't aware of that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Dir.glob("**/*")` returns an array like this:

```
['folder', 'folder/sub', 'folder/sub/sub']
```

Now when you do:

```
File.rename(file, File.dirname(file) + File::SEPARATOR + "2")
```

it will rename `folder`, but when it reaches `folder/sub`, that doesn't exist anymore, because you have renamed `folder` to `2`: it will be `2/sub` instead of `folder/sub`. The solution is to reverse the array. This starts the renaming process on the deepest level and works its way up to the top level:

```
Dir.glob("**/*").reverse.each do |file|
  # rest of your code can stay the same
end
```

As for your second problem, instead of:

```
FileUtils.remove_dir ("2", force = true)
```

You should use:

```
FileUtils.remove_dir("2", true)
```

First of all, make sure there is **no space** between `remove_dir` and `(`. That's what's causing the error.

Also `force` is the name of the parameter and by default it's `false`. That's why you see `force = false` [in the API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-remove_dir). If you want `force` to be `true` you *can* simply pass `true` to the function, like I show above.

Comment: Thanks, there is now no error. However, the directory remains :-(

Comment: @barry Not sure why it won't delete. What if you try `rm_rf` instead? By the way, I updated my answer with a solution for your first problem. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thank you. rm_rf still does not delete the folder - I'm assuming Windows is not allowing it? I'm getting a permission denied using the reverse sorted array after the deepest directory is renamed. So it is operating on the deepest directory first, which is some progress

Comment: Well, those are different problems. I don't know about your permissions and I don't know about Windows. Please ask a new question and someone may be able to help you.